# DataTables Custom Select Filtering by TR Data Attributes

Tags: javascript, datatables

I'm using DataTables, and added some custom dropdowns for filtering that have values of `<tr>` data attributes. Everything I've read mentions how to filter by data attributes to `<td>`. I'm not sure how to implement this as I'm not incredibly familiar with DataTables.

Created a Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/pegues/4bw5s0gd/1/

**HTML:**

```
<select id="custom-select-filter-1">
    <option value="">Please select filter 1...</option>
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>

<select id="custom-select-filter-2">
    <option value="">Please select filter 2...</option>
    <option value="four">Four</option>
    <option value="five">Five</option>
    <option value="six">Six</option>
</select>

<table id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Category</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-testattribute1="one" data-testattribute2="four">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Apples</td>
            <td>Fruit</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-testattribute1="two" data-testattribute2="five">
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Oranges</td>
            <td>Fruit</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-testattribute1="three" data-testattribute2="six">
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Lexus</td>
            <td>Cars</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-testattribute1="one" data-testattribute2="five">
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Winchester</td>
            <td>Guns</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JavaScript:**
$(document).ready(function(){

```
    $('#example').DataTable({
        order: [[1, 'Name']],
    });
    
    $('#custom-select-filter-1').on('change', function(){
        var selectVal = $(this).val();
        
        console.log(selectVal);
    });
    
    $('#custom-select-filter-2').on('change', function(){
        var selectVal = $(this).val();
        
        console.log(selectVal);
    });
});
```

I've reviewed the DataTables documentation, but do not understand how I could filter based on data attributes for rows, not column cells.

E.g., if `one` is selected from the first dropdown, then show all  rows with the match as in `<tr data-testattribute1="one">`. If the first dropdown is `one` and the second dropdown is `five`, then show all `<tr data-attribute1="one" dataattribute="five">`, and hide all other rows.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a custom filter for this using the DataTables [search plugin](https://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/search)

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function (settings, data, dataIndex)
```

This defines your filter conditions and pushes that function onto an array of filter functions used by DataTables whenever the data is redrawn (triggered by a user action such as paging, sorting, and filtering).

In your case the logic would be something like the following:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
    var trNode = settings.aoData[dataIndex].nTr;
    var attr1 = trNode.getAttribute("data-testattribute1");
    var attr2 = trNode.getAttribute("data-testattribute2");
    
    var val1 = $('#custom-select-filter-1').val();
    var val2 = $('#custom-select-filter-2').val();
         
    if ( (val1 === "" || val1 === attr1) 
        && (val2 === "" || val2 === attr2) ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
});
```

You can access the `<tr>` node for the DataTable data row via the table's settings object: `settings.aoData[dataIndex].nTr`.

From there, it's a matter of getting the attributes and comparing them to the user inputs. An empty string (empty input) means "no filter".

---

Here is a runnable demo:

```js
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
  var trNode = settings.aoData[dataIndex].nTr;
    var attr1 = trNode.getAttribute("data-testattribute1");
    var attr2 = trNode.getAttribute("data-testattribute2");
    
    var val1 = $('#custom-select-filter-1').val();
    var val2 = $('#custom-select-filter-2').val();
     
  if ( (val1 === "" || val1 === attr1) 
      && (val2 === "" || val2 === attr2) ) {
      return true;
  }
  return false;
});

$(document).ready(function(){

    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
        order: [[1, 'Name']],
    });
    
    $('#custom-select-filter-1').on('change', function(){
        table.draw();
    });
    
    $('#custom-select-filter-2').on('change', function(){
        table.draw();
    });
});
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.0.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.12.1/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

<select id="custom-select-filter-1">
    <option value="">Please select filter 1...</option>
    <option value="one">One</option>
    <option value="two">Two</option>
    <option value="three">Three</option>
</select>

<select id="custom-select-filter-2">
    <option value="">Please select filter 2...</option>
    <option value="four">Four</option>
    <option value="five">Five</option>
    <option value="six">Six</option>
</select>

<table id="example">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Category</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr data-testattribute1="one" data-testattribute2="four">
            <td>1</td>
            <td>Apples</td>
            <td>Fruit</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-testattribute1="two" data-testattribute2="five">
            <td>2</td>
            <td>Oranges</td>
            <td>Fruit</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-testattribute1="three" data-testattribute2="six">
            <td>3</td>
            <td>Lexus</td>
            <td>Cars</td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-testattribute1="one" data-testattribute2="five">
            <td>4</td>
            <td>Winchester</td>
            <td>Guns</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```

Note the use of `table.draw();` to trigger the re-draw; and note that the `table` variable has been added to the code which creates the DataTable, to support the `draw()` call:

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({ ...
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Basic use of DataTable is easy, but I have never worked with the more advanced coding of it. Your answer is perfect. I did end up making one small modification in case I ended up wanting to have multiple values in a data attribute. Within the if condition, I changed each to `(val1 === "" || attr1.indexOf(val1) !== -1)`.